# client denied by server configuration:

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, virtualhost

Entering website url in browser gets a empty notepad file downloaded size 0 kb. Website stops automatically and starts automatically. I am confused how is this even possible. Can anyone help me out yrr.

```
Error :client denied by server configuration: /home/ki687495/public_html/vendor/laravel/.env
```

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews -Indexes
        </IfModule>
    
        <Files .env>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from all
        </Files>
    
        RewriteEngine On
    
        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    
        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.ico|\.woff|\.woff2|.ttf|\.svg)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
        RewriteRule ^(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
    </IfModule>
    
    # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
    # Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
    <IfModule mime_module>
      AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
    </IfModule>
    # php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Sounds like your server side logic is unable to access that environment data. The result appears to be an invalid response which is miss interpreted by your client side system, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client denied by server configuration comes either if on wrong php version, check the documentation for correct version and if configuration are incorrect.